# HTML automatization script

Tags: javascript, html, localization, gulp

As I'm working as front-end developer I had encountered a major problem that takes a lot of time and resources which is language conversion in my documents.

One example: I wrote an mailing which must be converted from english to 14 other languages. As you can imagine it's boring and time consuming.

I was searching for a solution and I found nothing except gulp-replace which can be usefull. Here is short example.

```
var replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('templates', function(){
  gulp.src(['file.txt'])
    .pipe(replace('foo', function(match) {
      // Replaces instances of "foo" with "oof" 
      return match.reverse();
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
});
```

My idea is to write a gulp task that takes HTML files, one with all the translations and 13 other files with tags like:

```
<!-- REPLACE HEADER -->
```

In place where text should be replaced, it takes line form translations.html pastes it at tag place and it moves to another file and does the same thing with next line.

I would be grateful for any useful information that will help me with automatization.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a templating language, this is one of the standards: https://mustache.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

I want to recommend something similar to [GNU gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) in javascript. There is no official js gettext library, but you can use [jquery i18n](https://github.com/recurser/jquery-i18n) or roll your own translation mechanism:

Put the translations in a JavaScript structure:

```
var app = {}
var app.translations = {
  en:  { hello: "Hello!"
       , bye:   "Goodbye!"
       }
, de:  { hello: "Guten Tag!"
       , bye:   "Auf Wiedersehen!"
       }
};
```

Then you can read the translation strings in JavaScript:

```
var curentLanguage = document.documentElement.lang || "en";
app.lang = app.translations[ currentLanguage ] || app.translations.en;
```

And you can use code like the following:

```
alert( app.lang.hello );
```